# adding equations into footnote

Tags: equations, footnotes

I would like to ask how can we add equation into the footnote? I tried

```
\footnote{\begin{equation} some equation \end{equation}}
```

but apparently it does not work.
Any suggestion is appreciated

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\section{dsfsdfs}
This is to proof the proof works! This is to proof the proof works!This is to
proof the proof works!This is to proof the proof works!This is to proof the
proof works!This is to proof the proof works! This is to proof the proof
works!This is to proof the proof works! This {\bf is to proof} the proof
works\footnote{\begin{equation} some equation \end{equation}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you sure that your [TeX distribution is up to date](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55437/how-do-i-update-my-tex-distribution)? Putting an `equation` environment inside a `\footnote` works fine for me.

Comment: Incase you have a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) please include it

Comment: \documentclass{article}


\begin{document}


\section{dsfsdfs}


 This is to proof the proof works! This is to proof the proof works!This is to proof the proof works!This is to proof the proof works!This is to proof the proof works!This is to proof the proof works!
This is to proof the proof works!This is to proof the proof works!


This {\bf is to proof} the proof works\footnote{\begin{equation} some equation \end{equation}}



\end{document}

Comment: @Mu30 I took the liberty of adding the MWE that you posted as a comment to your question. The MWE works fine for me by the way.

Comment: How doesn't it work? What error do you get? Unrelated comment: you shouldn't use `\bf`, see [Does it matter if I use `\textit` or `\it`, `\bfseries` or `\bf`, etc.](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/516)